# Blackberry Maps for India

Tags: blackberry, maps

I am planning to develop a blackberry application which primarily uses map. Its an India centric application. After some googling I came to know there where no maps support for blackberry for India as of now.

I planned to use Google map API Static and Mobile Maps. As of now I'm loading the maps in browser field. Sometimes the google maps can't plot the direction for the given two co ordinates. I am not able to handle the response.

I like to know whether there are any other option to display maps in India. To show direction from one place to another place. I am getting necessary details from google Maps and Places API.

Answer (score 1):

There are some countries which blackberry can't show in its maps. You can use google maps instead. If you want it then go to web browser of device and type: `m.google.com/maps` and download and install it.

Then search code for accessing them. I have done it myself